# How to rewrite URL at runtime in php

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, xampp

There is [my site](http://pepper.pk/berrysnooper)

For SEO I have removed the `.php` extension from all links. Now I want to add `.php` extension using .htaccess file. 
How I can do this. I do not have any idea of using htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`MultiViews`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_negotiation.html#multiviews)

Let Apache do this for you.

Put this in your `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +MultiViews
```

Comment: XAMPP is an Apache distribution, essentially. So yes, this will still work.

Comment: Quote from [XAMPP site](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html): XAMPP is an easy to install Apache distribution containing MySQL, PHP and Perl

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^someName-([0-9]+)\.html$ someName.php?id=$1 [NC]
```

this will forward */someName-f435weS.html to someName.php?id=f435weS

source: http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/02/hide-php-url-rewriting-htaccess.html